# Ruby assignment with if expression yields nil

Tags: ruby, if-statement, expression, variable-assignment

In Ruby my function `func` returns `nil` if `myfunction1` returns a non nil value. I would somehow expect that `func` returns the value of `rc`. In other words it gets the value of the assignment even if it not executed:

```
def func
    rc = myfunction1
    rc = myfunction2 if rc.nil?
end
```

If I enhance `func` to this then `func` works like I expect:

```
def func
    rc = myfunction1
    rc = myfunction2 if rc.nil?
    rc
end
```

Here is simplified version to try it yourself:

```
def func
    rc = 3
    rc = myfunction2 if rc.nil?  # returns nil but rc has value 3
end
```

Is there is specific reason for this behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

Let's step through your simplified example:

1. You set `rc` to 3.
2. In the next line, you check if `rc` is `nil`, which it obviously isn't.
3. Hence the assignment will not be executed and since there is no `else` branch, the expression evaluates to `nil`.
4. Since this is the last expression in the method, `nil` gets returned.

If you want to return `rc` in any case, you have to resort to your second form or write the entire method like this:

```
def func
  myfunction1 || myfunction2
end
```

This will obviously only work if `false` is not a possible return value of `myfunction1`. If it is, you can do this:

```
def func
  rc = myfunction1
  rc.nil? ? myfunction2 : rc
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```ruby
if cond then expr end
```

returns nil if cond is false and the value of expr if cond is true.

```
if cond then expr_if else expr_else end
```

will return expr_else if cond is false.

This is why one can do (for instance)

```
value = if den != 0 then
         val / den
      else 0
      end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first definition of `func`, the last line has no definition for the `else` part of the `if`, so it is equivalent to:

```
if rc.nil? then
  rc = function2
else
  nil
end
```

You could use a guard clause to achieve your desired result:

```
def func
  rc = function1
  return rc unless rc.nil?
  function2
end
```